# Options page not displayed under Settings menu

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

```
<?php
/*
 *  Plugin Name: Official Treehouse Badges Plugin
 *  Plugin URI: http://wptreehouse.com/wptreehouse-badges-plugin/
 *  Description: Provides both widgets and shortcodes to help you display your Treehouse profile badges on your website.  The official Treehouse badges plugin.
 *  Version: 1.0
 *  Author: Editorial Staff
 *  Author URI: http://wp.zacgordon.com
 *  License: GPL2
 *
*/


/*---------------------------------------*/
/* 1. ASSIGN GLOBAL VARIABLE */
/*---------------------------------------*/


/*---------------------------------------*/
/* 2. PLUGIN ADMIN MENU */
/*---------------------------------------*/

function basic_treehouse_badges_menu() {
  /*
     *  Use the add_options_page function
     *  add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu-slug, $function )
     *
    */
  add_options_page(
    'Official Tree House Badges Plugin',
    'Treehouse Badges',
    'manage options',
    'wp-treehouse-badges',
    'wptreehouse_badges_option_page'
  );
}
add_action('admin_menu','basic_treehouse_badges_menu');

function wptreehouse_badges_option_page() {
  if( !current_user_can ('manage_options')) {
    wp_die('You do not have sufficient permission to acces this page.');
  }
  echo '<p> welcome to our plugin page </p>';
}    


?>
```

I am just a beginner and have written a very simple basic plugin structure.

What's the mistake that's causing the "Treehouse Badges" menu name not to appear under the Settings menu in the admin section of WordPress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue was that the capability was specified incorrectly when using `add_options_page()`. The capability should be `manage_options`. Note the underscore, no space:

```
function basic_treehouse_badges_menu() {
  /*
     *  Use the add_options_page function
     *  add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu-slug, $function )
     *
    */
  add_options_page(
    'Official Tree House Badges Plugin',
    'Treehouse Badges',
    'manage_options',
    'wp-treehouse-badges',
    'wptreehouse_badges_option_page'
  );
}
add_action('admin_menu','basic_treehouse_badges_menu');

function wptreehouse_badges_option_page() {
  if( !current_user_can ('manage_options')) {
    wp_die('You do not have sufficient permission to acces this page.');
  }
  echo '<p> welcome to our plugin page </p>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The manage_options is a keyword or manageoptions, which is w/o the sapce, is also acceptable.

Comment: You got it, Champion. The capability name is `manage_options`. [Check this page out](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_options) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

There is mistake in your code you use '**manage options**' instead of '**manage_options**'

so correct code is

```
add_options_page(
    'Official Tree House Badges Plugin',
    'Treehouse Badges',
    'manage_options',
    'wp-treehouse-badges',
    'wptreehouse_badges_option_page'
  );
```

[Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) you can read more about administration menu.